# sending automatic email for email-subscription

Tags: php, email, localhost, subscription

I am working on my project which is creating a online shopping store for seeing cameras and lenses . One of the features that I need to implement is news letter subscription . I do have the mail address of all my customers in my database . and by default I do know how to send email using php . 
But my main question is how to do this automatically without me being involved ? In other words , how can I send email like every day at 5PM without me being involved at all as a human being . (I am using localhost and Mac )
Thanks

Comment: If you still want to use php to send the mail, i would suggest a cronjob. That would do the trick

Comment: Cronjob does the trick yes but make sure that you have installed a mailserver since you're on your localhost.

Comment: Thanks for your response @JPJens

Comment: Thanks for your response @markvdlaan93